# sum of squared difference of multiple rows

Tags: r, tidyr

Made up a data frame. How to calculate the squared difference/error in hourly TMP and DW for 1/1 to 1/9 against 1/10? Need the sum of squared difference between hour1 to hour 24 of each day from 1/1 to 1/9 against 1/10

The output should look like

```
Date    SETmp SEDW
2012/1/1 X1    Y1
......
2012/1/9 X9    Y9
```

Data:

```
set.seed(1)

dataset <- data.frame(Date = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0:00", tz = "UTC"),
                                 to = as.POSIXct("2012-1-10 23:00", tz = "UTC"),
                                 by="hour"), 
                      TMP = rnorm(240), 
                      DW = rnorm(240))
```

Comment: So you want the last 24 hours as one side of the "differences" and each day as the other side of the "differences"? And you may want the sum (or is it the mean?)  of these squared differences (but you are not really saying which in your description.)

Comment: the sum of squared difference between hour1 to hour 24 of each day from 1/1 to 1/9 against 1/10.

Comment: My iPhone won't let me test code, but you should use [edit] to clarify within your question body.

Comment: sure thing.edited.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, we can get there using the `by` and `merge` functions:

```
# add day and hour columns (for subsetting and merge)
dataset$day <- lubridate::day(dataset$Date)
dataset$hour <- lubridate::hour(dataset$Date)
# split data apart
data_ten <- subset(dataset, day == 10)
data_one_to_nine <- subset(dataset, day != 10)
# for each date, merge to data_ten using hours
# then calculate sum of squared differences
do.call('rbind.data.frame', 
by(data_one_to_nine, data_one_to_nine$day, function(d){
  xm <- merge(d, data_ten, by = 'hour')
  data.frame(
    'Date' = unique(as.Date(d$Date)),
    'SE_TMP' = sum((xm$TMP.x - xm$TMP.y)^2),
    'SE_DW' = sum((xm$DW.x - xm$DW.y)^2),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
})
)

        Date   SE_TMP    SE_DW
1 2012-01-01 59.33207 63.41261
2 2012-01-02 42.04597 58.90700
3 2012-01-03 66.15492 51.81897
4 2012-01-04 31.83438 40.68851
5 2012-01-05 30.26666 59.30694
6 2012-01-06 45.05186 55.39751
7 2012-01-07 61.93305 39.76287
8 2012-01-08 37.08246 47.81958
9 2012-01-09 58.54562 64.79331
```

Comment: thanks. this is what i am looking for. I didn't know to merge two subsets first .How to do sum of squared difference for only max/min/average of 24 hours instead of all 24 hours?

Comment: you would modify the code inside of the `sum((x - y)^2)`